# How to access a data structure created in one function, in another function, without returning it or passing it in?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, scope

If I could, I'd just fix this by initializing a copy of the structure in the main function and passing that in to the other function, but I'm not allowed to change the function headers for this project.

Since I'm given this to work with, I'm also sure there's an equally good solution that'll help me learn something about how dynamic memory allocation can be used to make a function's actions last independently of the scope of that function.

My struct:

```
typedef struct AmNet { // this struct can be changed as needed
   int size;
   User ** users; // group of users in the net
   User *front; // the first user
   User *back; // the last user
} *AmNet;
```

The function to create is:

```
void create_net(){ // this line cannot be changed
}
```

In the main function in another file, called simply with:

```
create_net();
```

Then, for example -- this function should be able to access the structure, create a new User, and add it to the same structure's list of users.

```
void addUser( const char *name ) {
}
```

And the other functions within the same .c file as the struct initialization also don't take the data structure or return it, but they can access it and act upon it.  It's as if the structure should be able to be treated like a global variable.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Do you plan to call the "create_net" several times? Or is it rather used to create a unique instance?

Comment: Just to create a unique instance of it.

Comment: just make the instance of the struct outside of any function in the file.  Then everything in the file can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare a global variable, put the declaration outside all functions.

```
struct AmNet gNet;

void create_net() {
   gNet.front = NULL;
   ...
}
```

[Global variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) like `gNet` are widely considered bad practice. I can see no other way if you cannot change the prototype, but a `static` declaration will at least keep it in file scope.

```
/* in AmNet.c */
static struct AmNet *gNet;

void create_net() {
  gNet = (struct AmNet *)malloc(sizeof(struct AmNet));
  gNet->front = NULL;
 ...
}
```

Comment: How can I dynamically allocate memory to gNet with malloc, in that case? I hadn't thought he'd want us to use a global variable, for obvious reasons; upvoted for the static suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! I think in this case with typedef used to define the struct, it can just be gNet = (Amnet*)malloc(sizeof(Amnet)), too?

Comment: @Rohawk for that to work, change your `typedef` to `typedef struct AmNet {... } AmNet;` (without the `*`). Otherwise it will typedef a pointer to the struct.