# Why does putting a second value into this C struct's array turn the first slot's value into gibberish?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array of Users.  Currently my main function is testing this by putting in two names so the addUser function will go through both cases once.  The first value inputs without issue, and remains there without issue until the line:

```
amigoNet->users[counter] = newUser;
```

Then the second value falls into its second slot, but the first at users[0]'s name turns into something like:

```
S
    @
```

Where am I going wrong, and why is it able to corrupt the first element's value this way? I can't modify the User struct, but I can change AmNet.

Here's the AmNet struct containing the list of Users:

```
typedef struct User_struct {
    const char *name;
    Friends amigos;
} User;
```

The User struct:

```
typedef struct AmNet {
   int size; // hashtable size?
   User *front; // the first user
   User *back; // the last user
   User *users[]; // group of users in the net
}
```

The function that adds a user in:

```
void addUser( const char *name ) {
   User *newUser = malloc(sizeof(User));
   newUser->name = name;
   newUser->amigos = NULL;

   // if amigonet users is empty
   if (amigoNet->front == NULL) {
     amigoNet->front = newUser;
     amigoNet->users[0] = newUser;
   }
   else {   // if amigonet users is not empty
     int counter = 0;
     int flag = 0;

     // go through users until we have an empty spot
     while (amigoNet->users[counter+1] != NULL) {
       if (amigoNet->users[counter]->name == name) {
         flag++;
       }
       counter++;
     }

     if (flag < 1) { // if it's a unique name
       amigoNet->users[counter] = newUser;
       amigoNet->users[counter]->name = name;
       amigoNet->users[counter]->amigos = NULL;
      amigoNet->back = amigoNet->users[counter];
     }
   }
}
```

The AmNet instance is created here:

```
void create_amigonet(){
  amigoNet = (struct AmNet *)malloc(sizeof(struct AmNet));
  amigoNet->size = 0;
  amigoNet->front = NULL;
  amigoNet->back = NULL;
}
```

Comment: How do you create your struct?

Comment: And how to you allocate the `name` strings?

Comment: It's a global variable which is less than ideal [but necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822238/how-to-access-a-data-structure-created-in-one-function-in-another-function-wit).  The name strings are passed in as strings, in this case "jane" and "jack".  I've edited in the function that creates the AmNet structure.

Comment: Are you not allocating memory for amigoNet->users[0] and filling it or assigning some value to it since it is also part of the same structure?

Comment: It fills it if amigoNet->front == NULL, and it's filled successfully up to the point that the second value is distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
amigoNet = (struct AmNet *)malloc(sizeof(struct AmNet));
```

It does not allocate any space for the array `amigoNet->users`. You shall use:

```
amigoNet = (struct AmNet *)malloc(sizeof(struct AmNet) + MAX_USERS*sizeof(struct User_struct *));
```

or something similar. See documentation about flexible arrays in C99.

Comment: You do not need the casts in front of the mallocs

Comment: `User *users[]; // group of users in the net`

Comment: Ouch, this makes sense.  What would you recommend doing instead if we don't know the maximum number of users possible?

Comment: Use a linked list. BTW. Does somebody know why I can not edit or delete my own comments sent by mistake?

Comment: Thank you, that was what I wanted to do in the first place, but I can't edit the User struct to include a "next" member and link nodes together.  Do you see any way I could still make that linked list?

Comment: define a new structure `struct List_of_Users { User user; User *next};` and put a pointer to it to your `AmNet`.